# Setting up supabase locally issue with supabase key in Svelte

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I have setup a supabase connection

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = 'http://localhost:54321'
const supabaseKey = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsnR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJleHAiOjE5ODM4xsMTI5OTZ9.CRXP1A7WOeoJeXxjNni43kdQwgnWNReilDMblYTn_I0'
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)
```

The supabaseUrl is straight from the local insance of the app. the supabase key is obtained by running

```
npx supabase status
```

in the directory of the local instance of supabase

when I run

```
npm run dev
```

I get the following error

```
9:00:16 PM [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/lib/supabaseClient.js:
|- Error: supabaseKey is required.
    at new SupabaseClient (/Users/bob/Documents/dev/svelteSuperbase/myapp/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:58:19)
    at Proxy.createClient (/Users/bob/Documents/dev/svelteSuperbase/myapp/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at eval (/src/lib/supabaseClient.js:9:40)
    at async instantiateModule (file:///Users/bob/Documents/dev/svelteSuperbase/myapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:54360:9)
```

So I am running my supabase locally below are the details of the local sbase

```
   API URL: http://localhost:54321
     GraphQL URL: http://localhost:54321/graphql/v1
          DB URL: postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:54322/postgres
      Studio URL: http://localhost:54323
    Inbucket URL: http://localhost:54324
      JWT secret: super-secret-jwt-token-with-at-least-32-characters-long
        anon key: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJleHAiOjE5ODM4MTI5OTZ9.CRXP1A7WOeoJeXxjNni43kdQwgnWNReilDMblYTn_I0
service_role key: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6InNlcnZpY2Vfcm9sZSIsImV4cCI6MTk4MzgxMjk5Nn0.EGIM96RAZx35lJzdJsyH-qQwv8Hdp7fsn3W0YpN81IU
bob@bobs-MacBook-Air localsuperbase %
```

Comment: "supabaseKey is required." error is thrown when you have a falsy Supabase key. Make sure you have no spelling mistake when referencing your Supabase key.

Comment: its a copy paste there is no error in the key

Comment: Are you using environment variables to reference the supabase credentials, or is the code above literally how you have it in your code base? My guess is that you are actually using env variables, and you have a spelling error in the env name. This is where the error is thrown, indicating that supabaseKey is falsy. https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/blob/master/src/SupabaseClient.ts#L89

Comment: no I was using like it is in the code becuase I just wanted to get it to work so was not using the env variables to eliminate that as a possible cause